# Ways to define "Alternative" environment

Tags: environments

Suppose we have two/three ways to prove a mathematical statement in a non-rigorous context. What would be the best option for you to say the following?:

```
We will prove it [a math exercise, minority a theorem] in two different ways.

Alternative [Name of the alternative one]. Let...

Alternative [Name of the alternative two]. Let...
```

**What style would you use?** Would you use `definition` style?:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem*{alt}{Alternative}

\begin{document}
We will prove it [a math exercise, minority a theorem] in two different ways.

\begin{alt}[Name of the alternative one]
    Let...
\end{alt}

\begin{alt}[Name of the alternative two]
    Let...
\end{alt}
\end{document}
```

[image: Picture of the MWE]

Thanks!!

Comment: I know that this site is not a site for mathematicians, but I would like to read the opinion of people who are specialized in styles and conventions, in order to solve my doubt.

Comment: Why not `\begin{proof}[Alternative proof I] \end{proof}`?

Comment: @Sigur because theorems are not really what I should mostly use, but they are about various exercises on mathematics ("Calculate the derivative of the function..." and things like that). Do you still think it would be right to use the `proof` environment? Sorry for the confusion, now I edit my question.

Comment: So, what about a solution environment? Or `\begin{proof}[First solution] \end{proof}`. If you use the optional argument, the word *Proof* is replaced by the text in brackets.

Comment: @Sigur probably, but the white square is not needed. They are non-rigorous ways.